# Using a template tag within a form error message in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

My code contains:

```
Class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean_name(self):
        ....
        raise forms.ValidationError(mark_safe('....<a href="{% url edit %}">click here</a>.'))
```

I want to include a url that I need to pass kwargs to in my error message.  I'm using mark_safe so that my anchor text characters don't get escaped.

Currently the url that gets produced on the page is (current url directory)/{% url edit %} . Its just treating my tag as text.

Is there a way I can get this url tag to behave like normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, but it's a tad convoluted. `ValidationError` expects plain text, so you're going to have to give it that one way or another. But you can render the text yourself before feeding it to `ValidationError`:

```
Class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    def clean_name(self):
        from django.template import Context, Template
        t = Template('....<a href="{% url edit %}">click here</a>.')
        c = Context()
        raise forms.ValidationError(t.render(c))
```

`Template.render()` requires a context, which is why I just passed in an empty one. But if you have additional variables and such you also need to render, you can pass those into `Context` in the form of a dictionary.

**UPDATE:** As Daniel Roseman mentions, this is unnecessary for URLs since you can just use `reverse`, but if you need to render any other type of tag, this is the method you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there's no need to. The equivalent code for the `{% url %}` tag in Python code is `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

...

    url = reverse("edit")
    raise forms.ValidationError(mark_safe('....<a href="%s">click here</a>.' % url))
```

Comment: Haha. Right. I was halfway into answering his question before I even realized it was a URL he wanted to process, and even then didn't stop and think about `reverse`. Oh well. ;)